# SSL with Containerized Application

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ssl-certificate, certbot

I'm using an application built using `docker-compose` with three containers.

The application is [`SciNote`](https://github.com/biosistemika/scinote-web).  It's unclear to me how one would apply a `letsencrypt` certificate to the application such that the application runs over `https`.

Should `certbot` be running on the host?  In one of the containers?  Is there another means to apply SSL?